# Expression for "things we are responsible to share and work out together"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase for "things we are responsible to share and work out together"?

For example, we are in a team, so we have to work together and responsibility for every member is the same. Spouses have to share housework. …

Comment: Common responsibilites

Comment: Communal living?

Answer (score 3):

Group/ [Collective responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_responsibility)

At the workplace  (Wikipedia)

> Collective responsibility is widely applied in corporations, where the entire workforce is held responsible for failure to achieve corporate targets (for example, profit targets), irrespective of the performance of individuals or teams which may have achieved or overachieved within their area.

[In everyday life](http://wvde.state.wv.us/counselors/links/advisors/documents/11.28.doc)

> “In every situation including family and community life, work, and school, our actions have either negative or positive outcomes and impact our selves and others in some way.  If we show personal and group responsibility, we produce positive outcomes.”

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking at structuring the sentence better.

Try:

**Everybody shares equal responsibility.**

or 
**Everybody participates and shares equal responsibility.**

Answer (score 0):

Please consider:

> **liability** *noun* :  2. something for which one is liable; especially :  pecuniary obligation :  debt —usually used in plural

It sounds kind of formal, especially for housework, but it seems technically correct.

*from m-w.com*